# Load folder on specific Wordpress URL(category URL) with .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to load the content(index.html) from specific folder on specific(already used URL) in Wordpress.

Here's the .htaccess file(default):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I've tried with few variations of this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/category/funny-posts/ /funny-images/ [L]
```

So funny-images is a directory on my server where I have WP installed. Both of them are in the root folder.

How can I load index.html from /funny-images/ when I type www.site.com/category/funny-posts/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `index.html` file is not displaying (and the URI you want is being passed to WP) it's probably because you're putting the rule at the end. Try putting it just after `RewriteEngine On`. Oh, and I don't think you'll need that `RewriteBase`. Also, you don't need that leading slash in the new rule, just before `category`.

Your file should now look like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^category/funny-posts/ /funny-images/ [L]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: That actually worked! :)
The only thing that I need to do now is to fix the relative paths because in the index.html instead of getting /js/example.js it tries to get /funny-posts/js/example.js

Comment: Glad it did. You'll just need to use the leading slash in the reference to your JS file. Alternatively, use the HTML `<base>` tag.